# iOS - Swift SDK integration on an Unity App

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, sdk, implements

I may work for a company which wants me to integrate SDK to an app they paid for,

The app is made through Unity.

I didn't succeed to find any documentation since I'm not an Unity user,

For such an app can I implement SDK inside with Xcode, and can I use the SDK in the app code, even it is was made with Unity ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't super clear what exactly the SDK you need to integrate is. First of all I'd check that there isn't an existing [Unity Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com) package that offers the correct functionality. There are a lot of them, many of them are free, and integrating them is likely to be a lot easier than using Swift.

You cannot directly integrate Swift code from a Unity plugin, but it is possible to access native APIs using Objective-C. [Docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html). Assuming the Swift code you need is interoperable with Objective-C (and if it's an SDK it probably is), you may be able to write a wrapper plugin to allow you to access the Swift SDK from C# through Objective-C. For this to work you will probably have to build the SDK in question as a framework

But if you possibly can, find a simpler way.

Comment: Thanks, long story short the sdks are analytics sdk for advertisement efficiency. The app should display the analytics for their add campaign.
Ill check the doc you sent, thank you very much.